# Android / Java WebView Fileupload fails in Android version 10 and 11

Tags: java, android, file-upload, webview

I have an android app in which i have a webview. This webview contains a File upload for uploading a picture which does work like a charm from Android 6 to 9. For version 10 it does still work if i use a picture from the gallery but if i try to use one directly through the camera it tells me that it doesn't have permission to the ExternalStorage. I have given it the access in the Settings since i haven't implemented the permission question. For Version 11 it's almost the same except i get no error at all. I have checked some things i think its because the Intent for "ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" returns null for some reason. Did i miss something?

onShowFileChooser

```
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go

                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    Log.d("test", "Test1");

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "\"Unable to create Image File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

            return true;

        }
```

createImageFile() -> gives me error "Permission denied" even after giving it the Permissin in Settings

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        try {
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );
            return imageFile;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("test", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

onActivityResult()

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;

            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null || data.getDataString() == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;

                }

                Uri result = null;

                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                        result = null;

                    } else {

                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;

            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: did you find the solution ? could you share ?

Comment: I am afraid not, and the project got dropped, sadly.